# Does Restfb support real time update

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have tried facebook4j and it does not support real time update.
I am also developing a php endpoint but can anyone tell me does restfb support real time update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestFB supports realtime updates only by converting the JSON to Java object.

You have to write the endpoint that is called by Facebook yourself, because RestFB does not know which technology you use.

So a simple yes or no is not the answer. It supports you, but you have to do some work ;)

http://restfb.com/documentation/#using-webhooks

Comment: ok. Thanks. I am using facebook webhooks with flume so if i have to write callback myself then i might not use restfb then. :(